# Recursive Function(Decimals from 2 to 16) by using Java

Tags: java

Create a program to convert a decimal number to a number system from 2 to 16. Converting a decimal value to another number system should use RECURSIVE FUNCTION. Follow the format of the output below. Use your Lastname as the name of the class. Programs that did not use RECURSIVE FUNCTION to solve the program will not be accepted.

Sample Output.

decimal value: m
target base: n
value of m in base n is y
decimal value: a
target base: b
value of a in base b is c
decimal value: -1
thank you for using the program. bye!

I was just wondering if I am doing it right.

````
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            if(n < 2 || n > 16 ){
                System.out.println("thank you for using the program. bye!");
                break;
            }
            int number = n;
            int  stack[]=new int[16];
            int i = 0;

          while(number > 1){
            stack[i++] = number%2;
            number = number/2;
          }
            System.out.print("binary equivalent of "+ n +" is equal to ");

          for(int j = i-1;j >= 0;j--)
          {
            System.out.print(stack[j]);
          }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A recursive function is a function that gets its result by calling itself (recursively). Apart from the main method you don't even use any method/function at all, and there is certainly nothing like recursion going on in your code. So you kind of answered your question yourself, because your question itself states "Programs that did not use RECURSIVE FUNCTION to solve the program will not be accepted."

Comment: You are supposed to input a number in base 10 and convert it to some other base (2-16). You are only converting to base2 here.